# Angular+NativeScript ng build error: AppComponent defined in 2 modules

Tags: angular-cli, nativescript, angular6

I’m running Visual Studio 2017 15.7.4

When VS 2017 runs ng build with the “–prod” argument, Angular-CLI is choking on the fact that AppComponent is declared in both app.module.ts and app.module.tns.ts.

I’m not aware of any way to instruct the ng build command to ignore files by extension or regular expression matching against the filename – is there one? If not, that would certainly be useful.

I’m looking for your thoughts on how best to overcome this issue.

Comment: Perhaps one way to overcome is to build the porject via the NativeScript CLI in a terminal of your choice (e.g. bash or cmd) or via NativeScript Sidekick and overall emit the VS 2017 noise. Btw VSCode has great integration with NativeScript (and N extension available)

Answer (score 0):

The most expeditious solution is to use TeamMaestro's [angular-native-seed](https://github.com/TeamMaestro/angular-native-seed), which segregates the Angular and NativeScript artifacts and handles the build and dependencies separately.

See Sebastian Witalec's [article](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/code-sharing-between-web-and-mobile-with-angular-and-nativescript) for details on using this very helpful template.